# Logging Output from Racket Tests to File

Tags: racket, rackunit

I'm trying to set up a server to run extensive random tests against a Racket program, and want to have output from these tests sent to logs in files. How can I log output from tests to a file?

Tests from `rackunit` return `#<void>`, not a string, so trying to use `(call-with-output-file ...` with the tests only adds `#<void>` to the output file.

```
(call-with-output-file "testing.txt"
    (λ (out)
      (display <TESTS> out))
  #:exists 'append)
```

The output file should log the test results or errors if there are any.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at the `run-tests` function from the `rackunit/text-ui` module? https://docs.racket-lang.org/rackunit/api.html?q=rackunit#%28part._.Textual_.User_.Interface%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of running checks by themselves, which print to `stderr` and return `#<void>`, put the checks in a test suite, so that you can use `run-tests` from `rackunit/text-ui`.

```
#lang racket
(require rackunit rackunit/text-ui)

(define-test-suite testing
  <TESTS>)

(.... something something (run-tests testing) ....)
```

However, the `run-tests` function seems to use `current-error-port`, not `current-output-port`, to print test failures, so within your `call-with-output-file`, you need to set the `current-error-port` to `out`.

```
(call-with-output-file "testing.txt"
  (λ (out)
    (parameterize ([current-error-port out])
      (run-tests testing)))
  #:exists 'append)
```